# Cannot open database "our database" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'ADUser'

Tags: sql-server-2005, security, entity-framework, .net-4.0, kerberos

We are rolling out our first .net 4.0 entity framework application and are having an issue with security.

We have it working on our alpha site inside our development environment with the following setup:

1. SQL2005
2. IIS6
3. .NET 4.0
4. asp.net mvc 2
5. Entity Framework
6. NTLM

But when we moved it to our production environment for beta testing we are getting the following error via asp.net

> SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open
>   database "our database name"
>   requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user
>   'Domain\User'.

The only difference between the between the 2 environments is we are using **Kerberos** instead of NTLM in our production environment. **We have several other .net 3.5 sites using LinqToSql that run on both environments.**

We have already done the following:

1. Replaced an active user on another test site with the user that is failing to make sure it isn't an issue with the way the user is set up. - worked
2. Dropped and re-added the user from sql2005 - did nothing

The issue appears to be related to .net 4.0 as this is our first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between NTLM and Kerberos is huge. With NTLM, you can use pass-through authentication with Kerberos you cannot. With Kerberos and Windows Authentication, you need to setup a Service Principal Name (SPN for short) that tells SQL Server that it can be accessed by whatever IIS account you use.

[Understanding Kerberos and NTLM authentication in SQL Server Connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/12/02/understanding-kerberos-and-ntlm-authentication-in-sql-server-connections.aspx)

Here's another article on setting up Kerberos. Jump down to the section titled ["Configure a service principal name for the domain user account"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832769)

Comment: But we have several other sites that use sql 2005 and the others settings (NTLM and Kerborose). The only difference is that fact that this is our first .net 4.0 site

Comment: @J.13.L - Whether you are using Kerberos makes a significant difference. However, I would first ensure that the connection string is correct. Is the protocol being used enabled? Is the server name correct and is the server able to resolve the name correctly? Is the database name correct? Does the user account being used have access to the database? etc.

Comment: I have verified all these things. We have it working in our Development environment. So the only thing that changes is the connection string and we have verified that several times.

Comment: Does 3.5 cause security to fallback to ntlm where as 4.0 would not?

Comment: Thanks for you help, after doing some research on service principal name we were able to get it running...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, 2 questions:

- Does the login have access to the database in your production site?
- Does the database that you specified in the connection string on the SQL server that is specified in the connection string?

These are the 2 most common causes of that issue.  A Kerberos issue usually manifests itself in SQL Server a little differently.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Yes, via role=>schema.
If you second question reads: "Does the database exist on the sql server...", yes